# Saving last 30 seconds of audio in file using audio queue iOS api

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, audioqueueservices

I am using Audio Queue API for recording audio using buffers, I followed apple guide [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/AQRecord/RecordingAudio.html) .I want only last 30 seconds to be saved in the file in documents directory but this guide saves all the audio once a buffer if filled.

Comment: Did you manage to save the last 30 seconds only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to save only last 30 seconds using the buffer size of 30 seconds and in the end writing the data of buffer in a file.